# Facebook Graph - Instagram - "(#3) App must be on whitelist"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm trying to post to my instagram user, which was converted to a business profile per below docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing

I'm dropping the below POST into Facebook Graph Explorer:

17841407798762768/media?image_url=http://artfocus.info/storage/eI3kLElyCmmSzzFXwUla/UpU33k/MCBwWKjdmvf_large.jpg

And get the following error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3
"
  }
}

[image: Screenie]

This is obviously something very basic I'm missing, although I cannot see what it is. I'm using a published and live Facebook developer application in production.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? Which whitelist is it referring to. The page I'm posting to has a 'Connected Apps' area in the Instagram tab which is blank, I believe this area relates to the legacy Instagram Graph Apps, rather than a Facebook App which I'm using here?

Comment: Right on top of that first page you linked to, it say this: _“The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants at this time.”_ So, what exactly is unclear about that …?

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are recieving here is intended behaviour of the API. Publishing content to an Instagram Account is only available in closed Beta to Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners. This is noted in the /user/media documentation [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media). We are not accepting new applicants at this time.